# Find the relation with only the some parts of my data

Tags: r

So let's say I have a data set with 4000 observations, and I've used the typical code chunk:

```
relation<-lm(data~gpa+sat)

print(relation)

summary(relation)
```

The code above will give me the relation of the data and `gpa + sat` for all of the observations. I am trying to figure out how to create this relation but only for the first 2000 observations now and not for the whole 4000 observations.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you not filter the data ahead of time?  Or are you trying to see if there's an option within lm? Otherwise, filter data and use data2 in the lm call? `data2 <- data[1:2000,]`

Comment: Im trying to use lm and use the same relation of lm(data~gpa+sat) but only with the first 2000 observations this time. If I use lm(data~gpa+sat) just like as it is, it computes every observation

Comment: What does `class(data)` return?

Comment: Change the next line to `lm(data2 ~ gpa + sat)` instead then and use the subset of the data.

Comment: lm also has a subset option so it does seem you can pass a logical vector to it as well. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
dataset<-data.frame(data = rnorm(4000,0,1),
                    gpa = rnorm(4000,0,1),
                    sat = rnorm(4000,0,1))

relation<-lm(data~gpa+sat,data=dataset)

print(relation)

summary(relation)

dataset_subset <-dataset[1:2000,]

relation_subset<-lm(data~gpa+sat,data=dataset)

print(relation_subset)

summary(relation_subset)`
```